# Adding results to a visible AutoCompleteTextArea dropdown

Tags: android, user-interface, asynchronous, autocomplete

I have a search field that I want to autocomplete with data that I collect from two different places: a local database (sqlite), and a remote search API. I'd like to show the local options immediately, and then after a pause (so that I'm not making API requests on every keypress), start the API request.

The problem comes when the API request returns. **How do I add those entries to the (already visible) dropdown for the `AutoCompleteTextArea`?** Right now, I have a class that extends `BaseAdapter`:

```
private class MyAutoCompleteAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
    private List<String> resultList;
    private MySearchFilter filter;

    public BeerAutoCompleteAdapter() {
        super();
        results = new ArrayList<String>();
        filter = new MySearchFilter();
    }

    // getView, getCount, getItem overridden

    private void add(String newResult) {
        results.add(newResult);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private class MySearchFilter extends Filter {
        // performFiltering and publishResults overridden
    }
}
```

Everything works 90%. When I call `add(newResult)`, the new result gets added to the bottom of the dropdown. Unfortunately, the *height* of the dropdown doesn't change. If there were two results before the API request, and one comes back from the API, all that happens is that I get a scrollbar on the dropdown. As soon as I scroll, the UI decides "oh, yeah, there's room for that one too" and shows it.

I've tried `forceLayout()` and `requestLayout()` on my AutoCompleteTextArea, as well as `notifyDataSetInvalidated()`. No dice.

Comment: I had a thought this morning that maybe the problem is that right now, I'm using the Filter to get the local data, but then the API call and the add() call are happening from the parent class. Can I override the Filter in such a way that it does everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was looking through the [`AutoCompleteTextArea` source code](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.java;h=39714872dc7a934530b5be74639290285efd74ca;hb=HEAD) and I noticed that `showDropDown()` had the logic for calculating height and width, and that it does that even if the dropdown is already visible. I tried it (in addition to `notifyDataSetChanged()`) and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

The menu entries are displayed in a separate Layout, which is associated with the AutoCompleteTextView but not part of it. Calling `forceLayout()` or `requestLayout()` on that Layout *might* do what you're looking for.

You can also force the height to change by calling `getDropDownHeight` on the AutoCompleteTextView, adding some amount to it, and then calling `setDropDownHeight` with the result.

Comment: Manually setting the dropdown height seems like it would be a bit klugey. How do I get that View? There are a bunch of getDropDown*() functions on the AutoCompleteTextView but none seem to do the thing I want.